# linear-gradient for Bootstrap thumbnail

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, linear-gradients

I try to make a 3-column grid with images so that some text overlays these images. I found an example of the linear gradient for this purpose:

```
.card__content {
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85), transparent);
}
```

So in HTML I have the next:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 thumb">
            <div class="thumbnail" style="position:relative;">
                <img src="1.jpg" align="left" class="img-rounded img-responsive">
                <div class="card__content">
                    <h3>Matricaria is a genus of flowering plants in the chamomile tribe within the sunflower family</h3>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 thumb">
            <div class="thumbnail" style="position:relative;">
                <img src="2.jpg" align="left" class="img-rounded img-responsive">
                <div class="card__content">
                    <h3>Gulls, or colloquially seagulls, are seabirds of the family Laridae in the suborder Lari</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 thumb">
            <div class="thumbnail" style="position:relative;">
                <img src="3.jpg" align="left" class="img-rounded img-responsive">
                <div class="card__content">
                    <h3>Cirsium arvense is a perennial species of flowering plant in the family Asteraceae</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this gradient doesn't glue to the end of the image and climbs out to the right. And the thumbnail's border doesn't stretch for all length of the block, though without the gradient it did. Here is what it looks like now.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGyYq.jpg)

Please help!

Comment: FYI, Bootstrap has [positioning classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/position/#position-values). Even if it didn't, you should create your own rather than using inline styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a few changes:

```css
.card__content {
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85), transparent);
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
}

.thumbnail img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 thumb">
      <div class="thumbnail" style="position:relative;">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/13639773/pexels-photo-13639773.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-andrea-garibay-13639773.jpg&fm=jpg" align="left" class="img-rounded img-responsive">
        <div class="card__content">
          <h3>Matricaria is a genus of flowering plants in the chamomile tribe within the sunflower family</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 thumb">
      <div class="thumbnail" style="position:relative;">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/13639773/pexels-photo-13639773.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-andrea-garibay-13639773.jpg&fm=jpg" align="left" class="img-rounded img-responsive">
        <div class="card__content">
          <h3>Gulls, or colloquially seagulls, are seabirds of the family Laridae in the suborder Lari</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 thumb">
      <div class="thumbnail" style="position:relative;">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/13639773/pexels-photo-13639773.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-andrea-garibay-13639773.jpg&fm=jpg" align="left" class="img-rounded img-responsive">
        <div class="card__content">
          <h3>Cirsium arvense is a perennial species of flowering plant in the family Asteraceae</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it works!Thank you so much, this solution works perfectly!
By the way, it didn't work with my Bootstrap 3, but everything is fine for your Bootstrap 5.